# How to find location of a tag with 3 anchors using TDOA (Time difference of arrival)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to write a programming function to solve this problem!, however i need to know the Math function first so i can implement the function program.

in this picture
[Distance Difference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UKVP.jpg)

if image not shown? please view from here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue8k08cgzzy02z4/pic.jpg?dl=0

i am using this library on github for hardware for TDOA (Time difference of arrival): 
https://github.com/bitcraze/crazyflie-firmware/tree/52ecf3a0cfde0bf3335e0dbd6b27ce4cc4fd477b

the incoming data from the hardware according to the picture (which is distance difference) are these:

r1 - r2 = d

or

r2 - r1 = d

or

r1 - r3 = d

or

r3 - r1 = d

or

r2 - r3 = d

or

r3 - r2 = d

so (d) might be negative or positive

and these are knowns (anchor positions)

A1(x1,y1)

A2(x2,y2)

A3(x3,y3)

so i only have d, x1, y1, x2, y2, x2, y3 and the two anchors number that gave value (d)

Question1: Are these known input data enough to calculate the Tag position which are x0, y0

Question2: if Yes!, please demonstrate? with Mathematical/Sudo Programming function.

Question3: i included random (keywords) tags for the question because i have no idea of which type of questions in math is this question!, so if you do, please advice.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Tarik, welcome to MSE. In [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find how to typeset mathematical expression using MathJax.

Comment: If it is trilateration you're looking for, which you seem to be, [this "answer"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2969614/318422) might be of use to you.

Comment: You should explain what $d$ exactly is.