# Calculate a 3D Point when the distance to three other points is known

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, 3d

I have a problem where I want to calculate the position of a point given the distances to three other points. I have only found answers on this problem for 2D but nothing for 3D. I tried solving it using an equation system with three equations. Where every equation is the length of the relative vector between the point I am looking for and another point. Solving this by hand is pretty much impossible. I also tried to you use software to solve the equation system but could not get to a solution. Using this approach I would get two solutions I think. This would be okay for me.

I am sure this problem has already been solved but I could not find any answers online. I would appreciate any answers. This calculation should be done using code. So any graphical approach is not an option.

Comment: Similar, maybe it will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969363/finding-a-4th-point-in-3d-space-knowing-3-other-points-and-2-distances-to-the-4t

Comment: The answer of Nominal Animal is the solution. I have found code in Python using NumPy: https://gist.github.com/ctmakro/13a291cb7987ac3ce49c3c5608d7e3eb