# Expressing $\phi$ and $\theta$ in terms of time difference of arrival

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics, polar-coordinates, triangulation

I have an experimental setup consisting of three receivers with known locations $\langle x_i, y_i, z_i \rangle$, and a transmitter with unknown location $\langle x,y,z \rangle$ emitting a signal at known velocity $v$ which arrives at the receivers at known times $t_1, t_2, t_3$.

The time of emission, $t$, is unknown.

**I wish to write the angle of arrival (i.e. the transmitter’s polar coordinates, $\phi$ and $\theta$) in terms of the arrival times.**

---

Note that I am not asking how to *solve* for $\phi$ and θ, nor am I asking how to relate the transmitter's rectangular coordinates to distances from the receivers (i.e. the arrival times) which is, of course, trivial. I merely wish to express $\phi$ and $\theta$ in terms of the $t_i$’s.

[This](https://www.ese.wustl.edu/%7Enehorai/josh/students.cec.wustl.edu/_jly1/doa.html) WUSTL student research project comes close to what I’m looking for, but does so only in two dimensions and thus only for θ.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969363/finding-a-4th-point-in-3d-space-knowing-3-other-points-and-2-distances-to-the-4t

Comment: @TheBestMagician Thanks for the link. While this doesn't quite answer my question, it was an interesting read.

Comment: If finding ⟨,,⟩ of the transmitter is trivial, deducing from them $\phi$ and $\theta$ should be trivial too. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I misworded that a bit, my apologies. As far as I can tell, it *isn't* trivial to  express the receiver's rectangular coordinates directly in terms of the arrival times (WolframAlpha gives me: https://bit.ly/32Mz9BR). What I meant to say was that I am not looking for the relation $\Delta d = v \cdot \Delta t$, which is trivial to obtain and discussed fairly extensively elsewhere. The expressions for the receiver's polar coordinates should be relatively simple... I recall seeing this elsewhere, but can't relocate the source.

Comment: FYI - The three distances define three spheres about the three points. The intersection of two spheres will be a circle. This circle will intersect the third sphere in two points. I.e., there will be two solutions, Except for extremely rare cases, the three radii are not sufficient to completely identify where the transmitter is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Three receivers will only locate the sender at the intersection of two hyperboloids. This is a one dimensional locus. That’s why such a ground tracking system (and reversely GPS) needs data from at least *four* receivers (or senders).

Comment: @WimC - yes, I overlooked that the sending time was unknown, so arrival time does not translate directly into a radius.

Comment: What I don't understand about this question is that you say you don't want to solve for $\theta$ and $\phi$, but then say you want to express $\theta$ and $\phi$ in terms of the $t_i$. But finding such an expression is exactly what "solving for $\theta$ and $\phi$" means. So it remains unclear to me what it is you expect.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Apologies for the confusion. I've asked similar questions elsewhere, and find that I'm often met with (often generic) answers describing algorithmic procedures used to e.g. find real-world solutions numerically (e.g. least squares techniques), without actually giving expressions for $\theta$ and $\phi$. What I meant to convey is that I'm not looking for an explanation of some way to solve the equations numerically, nor am I concerned with their solvability. I simply want expressions for $\theta$ and $\phi$ in terms of the $t_i$. (Hopefully that helps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the distance to the sender is much larger than the distance between any two receivers.  Note that it is not possible to locate the sender exactly with only three receivers, but it is possible to estimate the direction to the sender. (In the planar example from the link there are *two* sensors at two different locations, so *four* sensors in total.)   Let $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in \mathbb R^3$ be the locations of the receivers and the unit vector $n \in S^2$ the (approximate) direction to the sender.  Then for two receivers $v_i, v_j$ the angle $\alpha$ between $n$ and $v_j - v_i$ satisfies $$\frac{\langle n, v_j-v_i \rangle}{\lVert v_j-v_i \rVert} = \cos(\alpha) = \frac{v \, (t_i - t_j)}{\lVert v_i - v_j \rVert}.$$ This leads to the equations $$\langle n, v_j-v_i \rangle = v \, (t_i - t_j)$$ for all pairs of indices $i, j$. Together with $\lVert n \rVert = 1$ this system has two different solutions in general, symmetric by reflection along a normal vector of the plane through $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Then write $n$ in polar coordinates.